# h3 and anchor inline-block (on same line)

Tags: html, css

I want to have an edit icon on the same line as my product title. I thought I could use `span` or just set both elements to `display: inline-block;` But I'm having trouble getting this to work.

```css
.model-title {
  display: inline-block;
}

.model-edit {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="model-title">Product Title</h3>
<a href="#"><i class="model-edit fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
```

Comment: simply put the link inside the title

Comment: This does work, both logically and by judging by this jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0bLvmxof/ . You might want to check what other styles apply to your markup

Comment: I think your code is working. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For placing 2 elements on the same line just use `display: inline-block;` property and if you want to use edit icon then you can use bootstrap icon: [source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .model-title {
   display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">  
       <h3 class="model-title">Product Title</h3>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </a>
      </p> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```